# Python 3: How to allow the use of a letter(string) as an argument in a defined string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a simple function which checks if what the user placed into the arguments equal the letter B (No reason. Just made it B.) This is my code:

```
def letter_check_B(letter):
    letter = str(letter)
    if letter == 'B':
        print("You entered B")
    else:
        print("You did not enter B")
```

However, when using the above code, by typing in:

```
 letter_check_B(B)
```

I get an error stating:

```
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

How would I go about to fix this without changing how the overall code works. I want to be able to make this code work by placing the letter into the argument (if that is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a plain `B` as a *value* in Python. The syntax will *always* see that as a variable reference. Since you haven't ever assigned anything to the name `B`, you get a `NameError` exception.

The `str()` function can only work on values; it'll work on an integer for example:

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
```

You could create a string value with a string literal expression:

```
>>> 'B'
'B'
```

Passing that to the `str()` function is a no-op (the same string value is returned again):

```
>>> str('B')
'B'
```

but it'd make your function work nonetheless:

```
>>> letter_check_B('B')
You entered B
```

Note that *any* method you'd use to get user input, would return a value *anyway*. The [`input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for example, returns an object (value) of type `str`:

```
>>> input('Enter a letter: ')
Enter a letter: B
'B'
>>> type(_)  # what is the type of the value produced by the last expression?
<class 'str'>
```

You may want to read up on getting and validating user input, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your answer. However, due to my actual code allowing both the use of letters and numbers to be inputted (which does different things), is there a way for a letter to be placed in without the speech marks? Also I do not want to use a global variable and assign the user input to that variable.

Comment: @Yuxie: the *user* of your program doesn't use quotes to enter a letter. They are not writing code. Look closely at my use of `input()`; there are no quotes around the `B` entered.

Comment: @Yuxie: instead, your code will have to see if what was entered could possibly be a number. See [How do I check if a string is a number (float) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/354038) and [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/379906).

Comment: Alright. So i'm taking there are no way to do everything I am trying to do in just one definition, and that I must first ask for the input before using it in my defined function. And yes. I have already worked on a code which utilises ''.isdigit() and int() to parse a string to an int. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Yuxie: That depends on what you are trying to do. Of course you can pass any value to your function as long as the conversion to a string will work.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is a *name* (the Python word for a variable); and `'B'` is a string with one character.

Since you didn't define `B`, Python is telling you that you are trying to pass a name that isn't defined.

Note the quotes `'B'` make a difference here. You need to pass a *string*, like this:

```
letter_check_B('B')
```

You should read up on the [string type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there a way to just allow the user to type in B without the ' '? Maybe using input()?

Comment: Just use input, like this: `user_letter = input('Please enter a letter: ')`, and the user can type `B` (without quotes); and it will be stored in `user_letter` as a string.

Comment: okay. Thanks for the answer. I'll go about to try implement that instead.